# Getting input on Scene2D UI elements with non stage InputProcessor

Tags: java, libgdx

My libgdx screen handles my input for my characters. I use Scene2D to draw the UI elements.
I have a few on screen elements drawn but I can't track input on them unless I set the InputProcessor to the 'stage'.

Is there a way to overcome this and receive input on both without converting my characters into actors?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491661/click-through-an-actor-in-libgdx

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent

Input Multiplexer solves this issue.

Thanks to P.T.